# Failure while sending batch events to azure eventhub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to send a batched events using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs call "[SendAsync(IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventhubclient.sendasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_EventHubs_EventHubClient_SendAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_Azure_EventHubs_EventData__)".

Is this a transactional operation i.e. is there possiblity of partial success/failure? Is there any official documentation confirming that there will be no duplicates if I resend in case this API throws an exception?

Answer (score 1):

- All `sendAsync` calls either all succeed or fail together--[partial success is *not* possible](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample04_PublishingEvents.md#publishing-events-without-an-explicit-batch).
- If the `sendAsync` call doesn't throw an exception, then the service will take responsibility of delivering the events. If it throw, then the events are *not* sent. If the request times out before getting a response from the service, then it's *unclear* whether the sent was successful or not.
- Everytime you send event(s), neither the `EventHubProducerClient` nor the Event Hubs service has any notion of identifying an event -- it's a new piece of data

(Your docs are for v4 of the library, which doesn't have the `EventHubProducerClient`. This is from [version 5.2.0](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-eventhub/latest/azure.eventhub.html) in case you're wondering.)

If you're worrying about duplication of events, then you'll need to determine what the needs of your application are -- is it better to lose data or to deal with it when processing? (You can add custom metadata to events to help you decide how to process them--[sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample04_PublishingEvents.md#publishing-events-with-custom-metadata).) Event Hubs has an [at-least-once guarantee](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services#event-hubs), so even if you don't publish duplicates, there is a chance the service will return some events multiple times. This is common for a messaging service.

If you have more questions about this, I'd recommend filing an issue in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues) where the new library lives.